# How do I backup account passwords and and other data on Catalina?

Tags: iphone, backup, catalina

I have always relied on using an encrypted backup of my iPhone to preserve account passwords as part of the backup, so that these can be easily restored when I move to a new phone. But this feature relies on iTunes, which has been removed from Catalina.

> [image]

How do I create an encrypted backup of my iPhone that preserves account passwords and and other data on Catalina, so that these can be restored when I get a new phone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://support.apple.com/en-in/HT205220#encrypt

Has the screenshot

> From the General tab or the Summary tab, select "Encrypt local backup" under the Backups section.
>
> [image]

Answer (score 0):

If you encrypt the backup, your account passwords and settings will be saved. In addition, your account preferences are usually automatically saved in your iCloud session . But, first do an iCloud Backup... for security reasons

> [image]

Comment: The question is how to create a (local, "This Computer") encrypted backup that saves passwords on Catalina, given that it doesn't have iTunes (where this feature lives now).

Comment: @orome This function is included in the option you have marked in the image of the question. If you encrypt the backup, your account passwords and settings will be saved. In addition, your account preferences are usually automatically saved in your icloud session

Comment: @RaúlSánchez the screenshot was of iTunes.. the backups are now done in Finder.

Comment: @ankii So this feature exists in Catalina, and is now in Finder there?

Comment: @orome I edited the answer with a photo of backup options in Finder

Comment: Re *first do an iCloud Backup... for security reasons* : Sometimes space crunch in iCloud makes people do local backups..